# Can't scroll inside video embed on iOS Safari

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I have a page that needs to render on mobile devices. on Safari the user is not able to scroll the pages when inside the video area. I tried applying `-webkit-overflow-scrolling : 'touch';` to no effect.

#### HTML

```
<div class="video-container" style="display: none;">
  <iframe src="{{ cms:page:youtube:string }}" width="500px" height="281px"> </iframe>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;'
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling : 'touch';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this very same issue it seems that the single quotes around the touch need to be removed.

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Works :-)