# Can't scroll my web page by dragging/tapping the video area in iOS Sarafi

Tags: html, css, ios, angular, safari

I made angular based web page that can share videos, but scrolling page by dragging video element isn't working on iOS17 Safari browser. Chrome and Mozilla is working well without any issues.

I have attached my code here.

mvideo.component.html

```
<div [class]="containerClass" class="custom-video position-relative" *ngIf="src && !isVideoBroken">
    <video [src]="src + '#t=0.01'" id="video" [class]="className" (loadedmetadata)="onVideoLoad()"  (error)="onVideoError()" playsInline (click)="manage_video_play()">
        Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
    </video>
</div>
```

mvideo.component.scss

```
.custom-video {
    >video {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        object-position: center;
    }
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch !important;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

following is the rendered html

```
<app-mvideo _ngcontent-serverapp-c128="" _nghost-serverapp-c124="">
  <div _ngcontent-serverapp-c124="" class="custom-video position-relative ng-star-inserted">
    <video _ngcontent-serverapp-c124="" id="video" playsinline class="hide-video-controls radius-12 w-100" src="https://indiefire.io:3306/videos/fanpostvideo/romchos_1696613147607_v09044g40000cgkr01jc77u4hlksm9jg.mp4#t=0.01"> </video>
  </div>
</app-mvideo>
```

I checked the following articles, but not helpful.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/740225

https://codepen.io/gem0303/pen/qBgEeaG

[Can't scroll inside video embed on iOS Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863129/cant-scroll-inside-video-embed-on-ios-safari)

Answer (score 3):

> A related bug report has been filed on Safari's official bug tracker:
> [Safari Bug Report #261563](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=261563).

This bug prevents `<video>` elements from receiving drag, and thereby scroll events.

As a temporary fix, you can add an overlay to the `<video>` element so that the overlay, and not the `<video>` element, receives the drag events.

Here's an example using a pseudo-element. Just add this class to the `<video>`'s wrapping element, adjusting the z-index value as needed:

```
.fix-ios-17-vid-scroll::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  content: '';
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work for me... for some reason the div with absolute positioning is being rendered under the video on the y-axis. This only happens on mobile safari thought, not desktop! My site: https://www.everythinggood.studio/

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is a bug in Safari on iOS 17.

A related bug report has been filed on Safari's official bug tracker: [Safari Bug Report #261563](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=261563). The issue has already been addressed and fixed by the Safari development team. However, as of now, Apple has not released a new iOS version that includes the bug fix.

In the meantime, consider checking for any announcements or release notes from Apple regarding upcoming iOS updates that may include the resolution for this particular bug.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as you, and since the other answer didn't work in my case, I came up with a different workaround which is basically to check the iOS version, and hide the video element on my page if it is in the broken iOS version 17. Here's my code, maybe it will help you:

```
getiOSVersion(): number | null {
  const userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
  const iOSVersionMatch = userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)\s+OS\s+(\d+[._]\d+[._]?\d*)/i);
      
  if (iOSVersionMatch && iOSVersionMatch.length >= 3) {
    const versionString = iOSVersionMatch[2].replace(/_/g, '.');
    return parseFloat(versionString);
  }
      
  return null; // Unable to determine iOS version
}
    
let v = this.getiOSVersion();
console.log("ios version is: "+v);
   
if(v){
  if(v>=17 && v<17.2){
    //hide the video
    this.showVideo = false;
  }
}
```

I've tested this and it works reliably on Safari and Chrome for iOS. It is not working using Brave browser, but Brave only has like .05% market share.